# how can I extract the name of a webpack chunk along with its hash to a external file like manifest.json

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm using the `splitChunks` optimization setting and also the `chunkFilename` property like so `chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js'` to give each chunk a hash.  Is there a way to reference the chunked file by a common name so that I can dynamically update my pages when the hash changes?

something like:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  vendorFile: venderFile.1902tjg.js
}
```

Where I can pull in that file and reference it in my template file

**index.pug**

```
<script src=#{manfiest.vendorFile} />
```

Comment: commonly webpack is for **client side** or browser rendering apps (react, angular, vue, etc). PUG is a **server rendering** framework, so webpack can help you just for your minimals js or css files. How and why are you using webpack for pug templates?

Comment: I'm using webpack to generate a bundle that my server needs to reference.  I'm looking for a way to dynamically update that reference rather than having to edit index.pug every time the hash changes

Answer (score 0):

If you have a folder with your webpack build result like:

- venderFile.1902tjg.js
- some.css
- etc.etc

Which is ready before the start of your nodejs + pug templates, you could create your manifest.json with these steps:

- Get the unique .js file name in your build folder. If there are several .js files, use a kind of regex

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var targetFiles = fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(function(file) {
    return path.extname(file).toLowerCase() === '.js';
});
```

- create your manifest.json using the unique file found

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj = {vendorFile: targetFiles[0]};
fs.writeFileSync('../../manifest.json', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

You could use the previous snippet as a package.json script

```
  "scripts": {
    "manifest": "node update_manifest.json"
  }
```

Or just as a code before the start of your express application.